# How to handle event inside meteor call or after call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I came across two condition Inside meteor call get result and add data but querySelector throws error and for outside get result from call but it execute before meteor call thus making result state to null any solution ? --- Meteor 1.8 react 16.8

```
        onSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            Meteor.call('Add data', name,surname,
                adharcard,addess,Mnumber,tags,product,
                (error, result) => {
                    if(error){
                        console.log("Add data error ", error);
                    } else {
                      console.log("Add data res ", result);
                      this.setState({kUserrId:result});
             //below line gives me error
    //TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null      
   console.log("fileupload24e",e.target.querySelector('#fileinput').files[0]);
//add result to db
                    }
                });

     // -------or--------- 
//wait for meteor call to complete and some how get result from meteor call    
          console.log("fileupload24e",e.target.querySelector('#fileinput').files[0]); // this work
    // now add data result to db
    console.log('kUserrId',this.state.kUserrId);// null
                }
```

Comment: The second option (below the "---or---") can NOT work, as this is immediately run without waiting for the Meteor.call to finish. You have to put your code inside the Meteor.call callback. Besides that, `e.target` has to be defined inside your callback if `e` is an actual DOM event. maybe `console.log(e)` somewhere, this actually should work, there is no reason why `e.target` should be `null` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event.persist() to get the event to not be null or undefined when is called in the callback.

```
onSubmit(e) {
  e.persist();
  e.preventDefault();

  Meteor.call('Add data', name,surname,
    adharcard,addess,Mnumber,tags,product,
    (error, result) => {
      if(error){
        console.log("Add data error ", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Add data res ", result);
        this.setState({ kUserrId:result });

        console.log("fileupload24e", e.target.querySelector('#fileinput').files[0]);
      }
    }
  );
}
```